# What is the difference between a database and a normal file based system

Tags: database, file

What is the difference between a database and a normal file based system (like how we store data in our drives)?

Is it that data will be stored in form of tables in database? Can't we store files (mp3, mp4 etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system:

> In computing, a file system is used to control how
>   data is stored and retrieved. Without a file system, information
>   placed in a storage area would be one large body of data with no way
>   to tell where one piece of information stops and the next begins. By
>   separating the data into pieces and giving each piece a name, the
>   information is easily isolated and identified. Taking its name from
>   the way paper-based information systems are named, each group of data
>   is called a "file". The structure and logic rules used to manage the
>   groups of information and their names is called a "file system".

From https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database:

> A database is an organized collection of data. It is the collection
>   of schemas, tables, queries, reports, views and other objects. The
>   data are typically organized to model aspects of reality in a way that
>   supports processes requiring information, such as modelling the
>   availability of rooms in hotels in a way that supports finding a hotel
>   with vacancies.

So a file system is the basic organization, retrieval / storage mechanism of data.

A database sits on top of some sort of file system but also provides various insights into the data (like relating and querying data) and other operations optimized for data writing and retrieval.

These days database is widely used to mean database management system (DBMS) which provides the various tools and mechanisms that sort, allow querying, index, relate, etc.

In all cases (I'm sure I will be corrected if wrong) a file system is required to have a database but a database is not necessary to have a file system.

A text file could be considered a database.

Answer (score 2):

> A database is an organized collection of data. It is the collection of
>   schemas, tables, queries, reports, views and other objects. The data
>   are typically organized to model aspects of reality in a way that
>   supports processes requiring information, such as modelling the
>   availability of rooms in hotels in a way that supports finding a hotel
>   with vacancies.

- [Wikipedia: Database](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database)

Facts regarding databases can be found in the link above. A file system is way different than a database. File systems store files, a database cannot store files.

I think you'll be best off reading the actual definition of a database, and you'll see it's far from the same as a file system.

Comment: Please avoid [link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: To fix this, you could include a short quote from Wikipedia, in a quote block, that would sum up what you're trying to point out. Obviously include the source too.

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Comment: @SriSaradaNutakki if this answered your question, please mark it as the answer :)